# Is it always allowed to substitute the absolute value of a function by the square root of the squared function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in the middle of a proof. I want to know am I allowed to substitute $ \left| \frac{\cos \left(3 x^2\right)}{x \tan (x+1)}\right|$ by $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\cos \left(3 x^2\right)}{x \tan (x+1)}\right)^2}$? (for real $x$)
I mean is it always allowed to substitute the absolute value of a function by the square root of the squared function?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: @surb why of course ...

Comment: @EasyTreyballSniper: Because $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: if the argument is a real number, then $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: @surb Yeah but thats not obvious, so 'of course' is misplaced. If its obvious, the question wouldnt be asked

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @EasyTreyballSniper - "of course" is misplaced since we have not been given for certain that we are only dealing with reals

Comment: "Yeah but thats not obvious" Yes, it is.  "so 'of course' is misplaced"  Quiblbe, "of course" doesn't necessarily mean something is obvious.  It sometimes and originally just meant something is a matter of course; bound to follow.

Comment: But I do think saying "of course" here is a little rude.  Well, "little" is a relative term and can be of significant size.

Comment: @fleablood "bound to follow" and "obvious" seem rather synonymous to me. The point is - without specification, it most certainly shouldn't be called obvious - this is how people get wildly incorrect results with complex numbers, like the standard ${-1=1}$ arguments you see. You must be careful and specify the domain you are talking about

Comment: ""bound to follow" and "obvious" seem rather synonymous to me. "  Not at all. Estate and probate law is bound to follow and are  matters of course, but not at all obvious.  This was something that used to drive me crazy when my grandmother used to say "of course" for things that weren't at all obvious; I always felt it just made me feel stupid for not seeing they were obvious.  It's an archaic usage and fairly rare now but it can be quite useful for a "now take note; this is key" alert. (Although it does come off as arrogant and condescending... sadly).

Comment: " The point is - without specification, it most certainly shouldn't be called obvious "  Well, I'd say it is simply *wrong*.  If $x \not\in \mathbb R$ then $|x| \ne \sqrt{x^2}$.  But as for when $x$ *is* real then it is indeed obvious that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. $\sqrt{M}$ is by definition the positive number that when squared is $M$ and $(-x)^2 = x^2$ so $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $\pm x$, which ever is positive, and that's the standard definition of $|x|$ for reals.

Comment: @fleablood I see, maybe the phrase is just used incorrectly a lot then. And for sure yeah, if we are in reals I completely agree it does follow - but just for the point of being rigorous - I thought I'd mention about the subtlety that complex numbers bring. As you said - just the statement **alone** without the domain specification it's just wrong

Comment: By the way, I am just quibbling and pontificating on the usage of "of course".  In this context it does mean "obvious".  And I *do* thing it's obvious but fairly rude to say so.... Also one common mistake advance mathematicians make, is in assuming just because something is "obvious" a hesitant student has no valid reason not to grab it and accept it. Not only are things only "obvious" by experience, obvious results may have a hidden catch.

Comment: " but just for the point of being rigorous - I thought I'd mention about the subtlety that complex numbers bring"  And that is *absolutely* true. And It's very important.

Comment: @fleablood For sure 100%. I agree. Even if something feels obvious - as you say, we should always try to explain it as simply as possible, because a student has not gone through the same training and won't necessarily have the insight to see it as obvious

Answer (score 3):

Just to be pendantic.

The absolute value is defined to be $|z| = \sqrt{z\cdot \overline z}$ where $\overline z$ is defined to be $\overline z = Re(z) - Im(z)i$ for a complex number.  And $z\overline z = Re^2(z) + Im^2(z)$ is a non-negatove real number, then $\sqrt{W}$ where $W$ is real and $W \ge 0$ is defined to be the unique positive real $m$ so that $m^2 = W$.

If $x$ is a real number then $x = Re(x)$ and $Im(x) = 0$ and $\overline x = Re(x) - Im(x) i = Re(x) = x$.

So *by definition* we have $|x| =\sqrt{x^2}$, by definition, for all real numbers.

However as  "the unique positive number $m$ so that $m^2 = x^2$" is $m$ itself if $m \ge 0$ or $-m$ if $m < 0$ we derive the "usual" definition.

$|x|=\begin{cases} x& x\ge 0\\ -x& x< 0\end{cases}$.

.....

Of course, (in the literally sense of being a matter of course, and not the more common sense of being obvious as this is nothing of the sort), although this is the way mathematics is defined today, it is almost certainly reversed engineered,  I strongly suspect we had the concept of absolute value as "how big something is in purely positive real magnitude" long before we worked out a consistent definition.

......

Or we could solve it.

$(-x)^2 = x^2$ and $x^2 = x^2$.  If $x \ge 0$ the non-negative $m$ so that $m^2 = x^2$ is $m=x$ and  $\sqrt{x^2} = x=|x|$.  If $x < 0$ then $-x > 0$ and the non-negative $m$ so that $m^2 =x^2$ is $m=-x=|x|$.

So yes, it *is* always true that $|x| = \sqrt {x^2}$ for all real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 2):

So long as we are in the realm of real numbers - this is fine yes. However - if we are in the realm of complex numbers, this is not true in general

Comment: But with complex numbers, using the symbol $\sqrt{}$ is not a good idea.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe How so? If we use the ${\sqrt{}}$ symbol, we are referring to the principle root. That is - take ${k=0}$ when you do the whole ${+2k\pi}$ business

Comment: Yes, principle square root of a complex number is well-defined.

Comment: I didn't say that it is not well-defined. I just think (it is my personnal opinion) that using the symbol is an easy way to do a lot of mistakes. I prefer not using it.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose So, if $x$ is real, I am allowed to do that? Right?

Comment: @katy98 correct yes :) since if $x$ is real, then all the stuff inside the square-root will be real. You can't though, say ${\sqrt{\left(1+ix\right)^2}=|1+ix|}$, for example. Since you are no longer dealing with necessarily real numbers

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Well - ${z^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ usually refers to the "set" of roots of $z$. So I'm not sure how else you would define the principle root. Ultimately it's just a symbol that refers to taking the principle root. You could just write down "principle root" but it takes longer, so there's not really any problem with it in my opinion

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Sometimes we see things like $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe indeed. But I think rather than avoid using the symbol itself (which makes the square root symbol feel sad and lonely :( ) - one must (over time) pick up the habit that actually that properties like this may only be a special case of a more general function

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, but it's *principal* (in this case, an adjective) root. "Principle" is a noun which means something else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct indeed by definition for any $x\in\mathbb R$

$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}=\cases{\begin{align}x\quad \text{for} \quad x\ge 0\\-x\quad \text{for} \quad x< 0\end{align}}$$